# Find biggest contour for shadow detection

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing

I have this problem in image processing and I couldn't find an algorithm to perform well under this condition.It's so simple to understand but I don't know how to implement it in ‍‍`OpenCV` or in `Matlab`, so any algorithm or function in one of them *(MATLAB or opencv)* is helpful.

**1** . lets suppose that an `image` and background of scene is like the below

[image]

**2** . We apply an edge detector to `image` and my `current image` will be like the below picture.

[image]

now **my Problem** is that how we can find the **biggest contour or area** like the below in `edge` image?

[image]

---

If you want original picture the original picture is
[image]

and in matlab you can get edge image by below codes.

```
clc
clear

img = imread('1.png');                 % read Image
gray = rgb2gray(img);                  % Convert RGB to gray-scale
edgeImage = edge(gray,'canny',0.09);   % apply canny to gray-scale image
imshow(edgeImage)                      % Display result in figure(MATLAB)
```

In OpenCV you can use below code

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
   Mat img = imread("1.png");

   Mat gray;
   cvtColor(img,           //BGR form image
            gray,          //Mat for gray(destination)
            CV_BGR2GRAY);  //type of transform(in here BGR->GRay)

   Mat edgeImage;
   Canny(gray,       //Input Array
         edgeImage,  //Output Array
         40,         // Lower threshold
         120);        //Upper threshold

   namedWindow("Edge-Image");       //create a window for display image
   imshow("Edge-Image",edgeImage);  //Display edgeImage in window that in before line create
   waitKey(0);                      //stick display window and wait for any key

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: You should provide your input images so other can process them if they wish

Comment: @Piglet Thanks for your comment, but this image cropped from an article  and in that article the authors don't explain how they identify this area, so unfortunately i don't have it, but i think if you apply an edge detector to most of images there is a biggest contour. but if this help i can crop the image from article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in Matlab using `imdilate` to close the contours and `regionprops` to get the closed objects area:

```
% Your code to start
img = imread('Image.png');             % read Image
gray = rgb2gray(img);                  % Convert RGB to gray-scale
edgeImage = edge(gray,'canny',0.09);   % apply canny to gray-scale image

% First dilate to close contours
BW = imdilate(edgeImage, strel('disk',4,8));

% Then find the regions
R = regionprops(~BW, {'Area', 'PixelIdxList'});

% Find the second biggest region (the biggest is the background)
[~, I] = sort([R(:).Area], 'descend');
Mask = zeros(size(img));
Mask(R(I(2)).PixelIdxList) = 1;

% Display
clf
imshow(Mask)
```

An the result is:

[image: The result: Mask]

Best,

Answer (score 1):

First close the contour with morphological closing since you can't find it now as it is not really a distinct contour, but a part of the larger one.

After closing, just use the [findContours()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) function and use its output to get the area of each contour and eventually find the maximum one by using the [contourArea()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#double%20contourArea(InputArray%20contour,%20bool%20oriented)) function.